# Nutch Crawl - Deleting segments on each crawl implications

Tags: solr, nutch

I noticed that during each Nutch crawl, the indexes sent to Solr were not consistent. Sometimes the latest changes to the webpages were shown, sometimes older changes were shown instead.

**Cause**

Noticed that Nutch was giving indexes from an **older segment** to Solr.

**Current Solution**

Deleting all old segments before fetching and seemed to solve the problem.

**Question**

Would like to know if there are any implications of such an approach or my understanding to this is incorrect. Would also like to know why does Nutch not automatically remove older segments during a crawl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple segments are indexed (again) and the same is contained in two or more segments, there is no guarantee that the most recent version is indexed. It's a known problem ([NUTCH-1416](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1416)). The easiest solution is to send only the recently fetched segments to the indexer. The script `bin/crawl` does this, the index step is done at the end of each cycle for the segment fetched in this cycle.